# ArrayAdapter.createFromResource() and ArrayAdapter. setDropDownViewResource()

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

Could someone please help point out the difference between the the two parameters that I highlighted. Aren't they the same thing, the layout resources used to create each view (or item) in the dropdown list? What does the `ArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource()` do exactly?. Thank you very much for your time. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `Spinner` or `AutocompleteTextView` you use `setDropDownViewResource` to identify which layout should be used to create drop down list items view.

But the first parameter identifies the layout that should be used to create view for selected item from drop down list.

**Note:** As I experienced, the last point is correct in `Spinner`, not in `AutoCompleteTextView`. Because `AutoCompleteTextView` is an `EditText` itself.

You can read more about [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) and [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#AutoComplete)